# How can I get an updated access token, using stored refresh token

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I'm building an application that allows the admin to authenticate access to their analytics account for offline usage, and stores the refresh token in the database.

Now when I try to use the API on the frontend, it returns the following error:

```
"Access Token Expired. There wan a general error : The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved."
```

Here's my code that generates this error so far:

```
require_once "lib/google/Google_Client.php";
require_once "lib/google/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php";

$_analytics = new analytics();
$_googleClient = new Google_Client();
$_googleClient->setClientId($_analytics->gaClientId);
$_googleClient->setClientSecret($_analytics->gaClientSecret);
$_googleClient->setRedirectUri($_analytics->gaRedirectUri);
$_googleClient->setScopes($_analytics->gaScope);
$_googleClient->setAccessType($_analytics->gaAccessType);

// Returns last access token from the database (this works)
$_tokenArray['access_token'] = $_analytics->dbAccessToken($_agencyId);
$_googleClient->setAccessToken(json_encode($_tokenArray));

if($_googleClient->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // Don't think this is required for Analytics API V3
    //$_googleClient->refreshToken($_analytics->dbRefreshToken($_agencyId));
    echo 'Access Token Expired'; // Debug
}

if (!$_googleClient->getAccessToken()) {
    echo '<h2>Error - Admin has not setup analytics correct yet</h2>';
}
```

I'm after a function to run something like setRefreshToken - entering the value from the database, from the admin previously authenticating it online.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try the following, you would need to add in the code to store the new token in your database.

```
if($_googleClient->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // Don't think this is required for Analytics API V3
    //$_googleClient->refreshToken($_analytics->dbRefreshToken($_agencyId));
    echo 'Access Token Expired'; // Debug

    $_googleClient->authenticate();
    $NewAccessToken = json_decode($_googleClient->getAccessToken());
    $_googleClient->refreshToken($NewAccessToken->refresh_token);
}
```

Comment: That fixed it, plus I was trying to refresh the token using the access token, instead of using the refresh token as it's param. #fail - thanks!

Comment: Do either of you know how I can force an access token to expire to test using the refresh token function to get a new access token? @mpark

Comment: @Anagio you should be able to run `$_googleClient->refreshToken($NewAccessToken->refresh_token);`
to force a new token. Then just compare the old token with the new one to see if its changed.

Comment: I get `Missing argument 1 for Google_Client::authenticate(),` any idea?

Comment: You can't call `authenticate()` without an auth code -- why is this getting so many upvotes and a checkmark?!?

Comment: Mark & RafaSashi : This answer was valid at the time, it looks like the SDK has been updated so this no longer works. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/migration

Answer (score 0):

Use a try/catch and use the catch for redirection/refresh of the access token. 
Below is the solution I used for similar problem:

```
$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
try {
$me = $plus->people->get('me');
} catch(Exception $e){
        if(!(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'logout'))){
         if (isset($authUrl)){
                $redirect = $authUrl;
        }
        else{
                  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] .'?logout';
        }
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        exit;
}
```

You can replace the statement under try with the line throwing the exception, I guess that would be

```
$_googleClient->setClientId($_analytics->gaClientId);
```

or you can also try refreshing the token as per solution given here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22096740/1675384