# google authentication expired token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I need to recover user info after javascript google login.
Authentication work fine and i send  googleUser.Ka object to my php where there's this code

```
$api = new Google_Client();
$api->setApplicationName($this->_configCustomer['google']['api']['application_name']);
$api->setClientId($this->_configCustomer['google']['api']['client_id']); // Set Client ID
$api->setClientSecret($this->_configCustomer['google']['api']['client_secret']); //Set client Secret
$api->setAccessType('online'); // Access method
$api->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));
//$api->setRedirectUri('http://www.infotuts.com/demo/googlelogin/login.php');
$service = new Google_Service_Plus($api);
$oauth2 = new \Google_Service_Oauth2($api);
$api->setAccessToken(json_encode($_POST));

//ADDED AFTER ERROR
if($api->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $api->authenticate();
    $NewAccessToken = json_decode($api->getAccessToken());
    $api->refreshToken($NewAccessToken->refresh_token);
}
//END ADDED AFTER FIRST ERROR


//$api->authenticate($_POST['access_token']);
if ($api->getAccessToken()) {
    $data = $service->people->get('me');
    $user_data = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
    var_dump($user_data);
    die();
}
```

this code generate the error:

```
The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved.
```

i added  code indicate from comment follow this link

[OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565653/oauth-2-0-access-token-has-expired-and-a-refresh-token-is-not-available)

but in the last version of php authenticate method require $code parameter. What is it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved in this way

```
$api = new Google_Client();
$api->setApplicationName($this->_configCustomer['google']['api']['application_name']);
$api->setClientId($this->_configCustomer['google']['api']['client_id']); // Set Client ID
$api->setClientSecret($this->_configCustomer['google']['api']['client_secret']); //Set client Secret
$api->setAccessType('online'); // Access method
$api->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));
$api->setRedirectUri('postmessage');
$result = $api->verifyIdToken($_POST['id_token']);
```

i send id_token, obtained from the ajax login, and recovery user info using verifyIdToken method of client library